# Cross compiling and CMake?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm building an embedded Linux system for ARM, and one of the applications is using CMake:

```
cmake \
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/mnt/system_rootfs ../app_src_dir
```

If CMake is executed like this, it searches the whole file system for libraries, header files etc.

How can I restrict CMake to ONLY search `/opt/arm-toolchain` and `/mnt/system_rootfs` for header files, libraries and programs?

Build system is Debian Wheezy and CMake version is 2.8.9

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for searching header files, libraries.

```
cmake \
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/mnt/system_rootfs ../app_src_dir
    -D CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/include/path
    -D CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/path/
```